remote end hung up unexpectedly with Writing objects: 0% (1/23640040)
I am trying push on remote, it was working fine till now but it started throwing error
Compressing objects: 100% (3749063/3749063), done.
Writing objects:   0% (1/23640040)
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have added below configs too, but no luck. Any pointers. Why it is failing at 0%.
I have added below configs too, but no luck.
 git config --global core.compression 0
   git config --global core.packedGitLimit 512m
   git config --global core.packedGitWindowSize  512m
   git config --global ssh.postBuffer  52428800
   git config --global http.postBuffer  52428800
   git config --global pack.deltaCacheSize  2047m
   git config --global pack.packSizeLimit  2047m
   git config --global pack.windowMemory  2047m 


Increase the post and ssh buffer size to
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
git config --global ssh.postBuffer 157286400

